# Reverse and get_absoulute_url with django 2.0

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an error when accesing my url "...pokemon/list/"

```
Reverse for 'pkmn-detail' not found. 'pkmn-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

What i'm trying to do is first show a list of the created pokemons, then link to the detail page of each one through it's number.

I have defined a get_absoulte_url method and used reverse with it in my model, so here are my models, views, urls and templates relevant:

pokeworld/models.py

```
class Pokemon(models.Model):
    pkmn_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    pkmn_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pkmn_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='Normal')
    pkmn_desc = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pkmn_slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='pkmn_name', unique_with='pkmn_number')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pkmn-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

pokeworld/views.py

```
class PokemonList(ListView):
    model = Pokemon
    template_name = 'pokeworld/pokemonlist.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pokemon.objects.all().order_by('pkmn_number')

def PokemonDetail(request, pk):
    try:
        pokemon_id = Pokemon.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Pokemon.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Pokemon does not exist")

    return render(request, 'pokemondetail.html', context={'pkmn_id':pkmn_id})
```

pokeworld/templates/pokeworld/pokemondetail.html

```
{% extends 'baseP.html' %}
{% block title %} Detail {{ pkmn.pkmn_name }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>#{{ pkmn.pkmn_number }} {{ pkmn.pkmn_name }}</h1>
<p><strong>Type:</strong> {{ pkmn.pkmn_type }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

pokeworld/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('pokemon/list/', PokemonList.as_view(), name='pkmn-list'),
    path('pokemon/detail/<int:pk>', PokemonDetail, name='pkmn-detail'),
```

I really don't know what to edit, i've searched and searched but i don't know if i'm not understading the solutions that others have been given or if i have a made a mess in my code, i'm really hoping someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: `path('pokemon/detail/<int:pk>', PokemonDetail, name='pkmn-detail')` maybe you need to add `PokemonDetail.as_view()` ?

Comment: No, that's not it. `PokemonDetail` is a function. PEP8 asks to write it in snake case as `pokemon_detail` to avoind confusing it with a class.

Comment: Your template location may be wrong, should it be `pokeworld/pokemondetail.html` (with the subdir `pokeworld/`)?

Comment: Is that your top-level `urls.py` (looks like it's in an app)? Have you included it in your project level `urls.py` under a namespace?

Comment: Why mixin CBV and FBV. When you already started to use `ListView`, why don't you use `DetailView`?

Comment: Yes that is an application and i've included the urls in the project's 
    urls.py

Comment: So i should use DetailView and change from using a FBV to using both CBV?

Also i will keep in mind the snake case next time im writing FBV, thanks for the advice @C14L . Also the templates do work under that directory for other views, and the ListView did work until i added the reverse method to link the DetailPokemon view